# MongoDB Aggregate same id different status wise record needed

Tags: mongodb

I have a this type of records in mongoDB same auctioncode and status wise i need a records
in auctioncode is the unique field. i want status 'FAILED' and same auctioncode not in the status of 'RUNNING' and 'SCHEDULED' OR case

please help me find the solution

```
[
    { 
    gemstone:"Champagne Glass"
    auctioncode:"RA0008343433"
    stockcode:"3273373"
    productname:"Champagne Beads Earrings and Faux Leather Lariat Necklace (24 in) in I..."
    quantity:1
    createddate:2021-04-08T06:08:08.000+00:00
    estimatedretailvalue:59.99
    material:"Mix Metal"
    targetsellingprice:9.99
    approved:true
    startprice:1
    incrementAmount:1
    status:"FAILED"
    enddate:2021-08-13T14:10:15.000+00:00
    startdate:2021-07-02T15:18:15.000+00:00
    paid:false 
    },
    { 
    gemstone:"Champagne Glass"
    auctioncode:"RA0008343433"
    stockcode:"3273373"
    productname:"Champagne Beads Earrings and Faux Leather Lariat Necklace (24 in) in I..."
    quantity:1
    createddate:2021-04-08T06:08:08.000+00:00
    estimatedretailvalue:59.99
    material:"Mix Metal"
    targetsellingprice:9.99
    approved:true
    startprice:1
    incrementAmount:1
    status:"RUNNING"
    enddate:2021-08-13T14:10:15.000+00:00
    startdate:2021-07-02T15:18:15.000+00:00
    paid:false 
    },
    { 
    gemstone:"Champagne Glass"
    auctioncode:"RA0008343433"
    stockcode:"3273373"
    productname:"Champagne Beads Earrings and Faux Leather Lariat Necklace (24 in) in I..."
    quantity:1
    createddate:2021-04-08T06:08:08.000+00:00
    estimatedretailvalue:59.99
    material:"Mix Metal"
    targetsellingprice:9.99
    approved:true
    startprice:1
    incrementAmount:1
    status:"SCHEDULED"
    enddate:2021-08-13T14:10:15.000+00:00
    startdate:2021-07-02T15:18:15.000+00:00
    paid:false 
    }
  ]
```

I this is same product auctioncode is same but status is different i need to get only **Status of Failed** records

status wise records needed for in the group of auctioncode

```
    [
        { 
        gemstone:"Champagne Glass"
        auctioncode:"RA0008343433"
        stockcode:"3273373"
        productname:"Champagne Beads Earrings and Faux Leather Lariat Necklace (24 in) in I..."
        quantity:1
        createddate:2021-04-08T06:08:08.000+00:00
        estimatedretailvalue:59.99
        material:"Mix Metal"
        targetsellingprice:9.99
        approved:true
        startprice:1
        incrementAmount:1
        status:"FAILED"
        enddate:2021-08-13T14:10:15.000+00:00
        startdate:2021-07-02T15:18:15.000+00:00
        paid:false 
        }
]

**my Mongodb Query**

[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'bids', 
      'let': {
        'id': '$_id'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$and': [
                {
                  '$eq': [
                    '$auctioncode', '$$id'
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'bids'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '$and': [
        {
          'status': {
            '$ne': 'RUNNING'
          }
        }, {
          'status': {
            '$ne': 'SCHEDULED'
          }
        }, {
          'status': {
            '$eq': 'FAILED'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    '$facet': {
      'products': [
        {
          '$skip': 0
        }, {
          '$limit': 150
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I am unable to understand your question or need.  Please revise your question for more clarity.

Comment: I have a multiple records and i need to filter auctioncode and status auctioncode contains more records but i need to get data from status 'FAILED' means the status for auctioncode only one 'FAILED' status record only i want. understand now @barrypicker

Comment: Still not sure.  So, if I may, what I believe you are asking for is a query that will find a specific `actioncode` where the status is `FAILED`, and that you may have more than one record returned, but you only want one?  Is this correct?  If so, which one?  Any arbitrary matching record?  Your sample aggregation query shows a $lookup which implies a join to a collection called `bids`.  You have not mentioned this collection in your post other than the query code.  This complicates things a bit and I am not clear on it's involvement.

Comment: yes auctioncode have one or more records but i need one records which only auctioncode available FAILED. if same auction code contains either one 'RUNNING' or 'SCHEDULED' skip the row @barrypicker

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments in the post it seems the following query will suffice...

**Syntax**

`db.<COLLECTION>.find( { "auctioncode": "<AUCTIONCODE>", "status": "FAILED" } )`

... where `<COLLECTION>` needs to be replaced with the name of your collection, and `<AUCTIONCODE>` is the action code you wish to filter upon.

**Example**

`db.bids.find( { "auctioncode": "RA0008343433", "status": "FAILED" } )`